# I have the following usages of maps with pair as a key and it segfaults. Any Ideas?

Tags: c++, stl

I simpled the example to help with reability. Error follows the code:

```
    #include <map>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;



    class A
    {

    public:
        map<pair<string, string>, string* > m;
        string str;

        A():str("sdfsd")
        {
            m[make_pair("aa","bb")]=&str;

        }   
        void foo()
        {
            map<pair<string, string>, string*>::iterator iter =m.begin();
            cout<<"In A::foo:\n";
            for(; iter!=m.end(); iter++)
            {
                pair<string, string> keys=iter->first;
                cout<<"map and test = "<<str<<" and "<<*iter->second<<endl;
            }
        } 
    };

    int main()
    {
    A a;
    a.foo();
    }
```

In core file:

```
 #0  0x0066f6c7 in std::string::_Rep::_M_grab () from
 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
 #1  0x0066f80c in std::basic_string,
 std::allocator >::basic_string
 () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
 #2  0x087e1e69 in pair (this=0xbfff7070,
 _ctor_arg=@0x9c087d0) at (pair keys=iter->first;)
```

Comment: you probably messed up another thing. I think that example is fine. Please show the "non-simpled" code. Is it all that one program? Or does your program consist of a binary library? Iirc, libstdc++.so.5 is pretty old. Could be an ABI issue.

Comment: weirdly I fixed it with const pair<string, string>& keys=iter->first;

Same here, the above program run, but the same exact pattern in a 

big program doesn't. I am sorry but the code is proprietary and cannot be posted

Comment: [Application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a compiler problem? It looks like some weird compiler optimisation, especially when aliasing iter->first makes the difference.

Just posted onto online compiler at http://codepad.org/ZhYvtj9v 
and it gave the correct result, without segfault.